# Proving convexity of a function using Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

The question is:

> State true or false:
> The function, $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ = $2x_1^2 + 3x_2^2 + 2x_3^2− 3x_1x_2 − x_2x_3 − 2x_1x_3$ is convex.

This is a part of a course that is mostly just linear algebra and I know it has something to do with finding whether all eigenvalues are positive or not. But that's just dirty work. I could not find any theory behind it to study it more wholly and completely.

(I did get the eigenvalues as positive by the way => hence convex)

Comment: Do you mean you want to know  the theory behind the statement “all positive eigenvalues $\Rightarrow$ convex”?

Comment: In this case you can read the second derivatives directly from the polynomial and see that they are all constant, thus the curvature is constant in every point (positive->convex, negative->concave). Alternatively to calculating the eigenvalues directly you can calculate the determinants of the first three leading minors and find that they are all positive, which implies that the hessian is positive definite (all eigenvalues strictly positive).

Answer (score 0):

You have a function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ which can be written in the form $f(x) = x'Hx$ where $H$ is a symmetric matrix.

The intuition is that $f$ is convex if and only if the restriction of $f$ to any line is still convex.

That is, you want to check that for any $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $v \in \mathbb R_0^n$ the functions
$$ \phi(t) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R : t \mapsto f(x + tv) = (x+tv)'H(x+tv) $$
are all convex. With simple algebra you can expand the product $(x + tv)'H(x+tv)$ which will give you a polynomial in $t$.Then you will find that the condition for all these functions to be convex is exactly that

$$ v'Hv \geq 0 \quad \forall v \in \mathbb R^n, v \neq 0$$

When this above condition on $H$ is met we say that $H$ is non-negative definite which is equivalent to all the eigenvalues of $H$ being greater or equal to $0$.

To see why negative eigenvalues would cause problems imagine that we had an eigenvector $e_i$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda_i <0$ then we would have

$$ e_i'He_i  = \lambda e_i'e_i = \lambda \Vert e_i \Vert^2 < 0.$$

---

For more general functions we would consider the Hessian matrix defined as

$$ H := \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}\right)_{ij}$$

and look at the sign of $v'Hv$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you got to the f(x+tv) equation after stating, "restriction of  to any line is still convex."? I have a brief idea of what "restriction ... convex" might mean. Should I evaluate the function after fixing the n - 1 dimensions? For example, for 3D, one might fix a line y = 0 and then evaluate a paraboloid as a parabola in 2D.

Comment: @ArnavMangla Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and fix a line $L \subset \mathbb R^n$. Then you consider the restriction of $f$ to $L$. That is, consider the function $f : L \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. Since $L$ is a line in can be written in the form $L = \{ x + t v : t  \in \mathbb R \}$  for some $x$ and $v \neq 0$ so we can view a function defined on $L$ as a function of $t$ because each $t$ uniquely defines a point on the line. This function is the function which maps $t \to f(x + tv)$.